# How to include <?php echo $page; ?> inside contact form 7 email in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, html-email, shortcode, contact-form-7

How I can include dynamically name of page `<?php echo $page; ?>` inside contact form 7 in wordpress? I put code into "functions.php" but it is not working.

```
function cs7() {
  $var='<?php echo $page; ?>';
  $html='<p>'.$var.'</p>';
  return $html;
}

 add_shortcode('cs7', 'cs7');
```

Comment: `<?php echo $page; ?>';` you are already inside a php block, dont open a new one. also `$page` is outside of the function scope.

Comment: I corrected this but it stll doesn't work. In my contact form i see [cs7] this shortcode doesn't work.

Comment: show us the code you are now trying.

Comment: function cs7() {
    $var=$page;
    $html='<p>'.$var.'</p>';
    return $html;
}

add_shortcode('cs7', 'cs7');

Comment: $page is still outside the function scope.

Comment: What is "$page" and where is that variable coming from?

Comment: I was wrong - I don't need $page variable but title of wordpress post. For example - I am on page with title one so I see "one" on my contact form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CF7 special Mail tag to display page or post title from which the form submitted in the mail content.

```
[_post_title]
```

More info [here](https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/)